# Как заменить цифры из массива

Tags: php, php7

голову уже сломал
есть массив `$arr = array('a'=>'01','A'=>'02','g'=>'03','e'=>'04','c'=>'05','d'=>'06','V'=>'07','O'=>'08','K'=>'09','X'=>'11','F'=>'12','T'=>'13','h'=>'14','n'=>'15','B'=>'16','Q'=>'17','M'=>'18','t'=>'19');`

есть значение

```
$str = '204114214206109209209';
```

Делал так но не работает как надо

```
$str = strtr($str, array_flip($arr));
```

Проблема в том что нужно чтобы он заменял в тексте только цифры из 3 только 2,3, т.е. вот так

<strike>2</strike> **04** <strike>1</strike> **14** <strike>2</strike> **14** <strike>2</strike> **06** <strike>1</strike> **09** <strike>2</strike> **09** <strike>2</strike> **09**

на выходе должно быть так

2  e 1  h 2  h 2  d 1  K 2  K 2  K

возможно тут надо регуляркой делать замену, но вот с ней у меня беда(

Comment: Ну вроде же всё правильно: для первого символа в строке "2" соответствий не найдено, он не заменяется ничем; для "04" есть соответствие "e"; для "11" есть "Х". Далее всё так же, как вам и нужно: `2 e X 4 2 h 2 d 1 K 2 K 2 K`.

Comment: нет не должно быть 11, цифры через каждые 2 знака не должны изменятся, только которые между ними 2 04 1 14 2 14 2 06 1 09 2 09 2 09

Comment: 2 e 1 h 2 h 2 d 1 K 2 K 2 K - это я расписал как должно быть 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *возможно тут надо регуляркой делать замену*

Можно просто в цикле собрать строку для передачи в strtr():

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => '01',
    'A' => '02',
    'g' => '03',
    'e' => '04',
    'c' => '05',
    'd' => '06',
    'V' => '07',
    'O' => '08',
    'K' => '09',
    'X' => '11',
    'F' => '12',
    'T' => '13',
    'h' => '14',
    'n' => '15',
    'B' => '16',
    'Q' => '17',
    'M' => '18',
    't' => '19'
);

$str = '204114214206109209209';
$new = '';

foreach (str_split($str) as $i => $char) {
    $new .= --$i % 3 ? "$char " : $char;
}

$str = strtr($new, array_flip($arr));
echo $str;
```

Результат:

```
2 e 1 h 2 h 2 d 1 K 2 K 2 K
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array('a'=>'01','A'=>'02','g'=>'03','e'=>'04','c'=>'05','d'=>'06','V'=>'07','O'=>'08','K'=>'09','X'=>'11','F'=>'12','T'=>'13','h'=>'14','n'=>'15','B'=>'16','Q'=>'17','M'=>'18','t'=>'19');

$str = '204114214206109209209';
$arr_str = str_split($str, 3);

$result = "";
foreach($arr_str as $str){
   $num = (int)$str[0];
   $str = strtr(substr($str, 1), array_flip($arr));
   $result .= "{$num}{$str}";
}

var_dump($result);
```

Вывод :

```
string(14) "2e1h2h2d1K2K2K"
```